# How to print the name of a recursive lambda template?

Tags: c++, debugging, recursion, lambda, macros

For debug purpose, would it be possible to use any macro to print the name of a recursively defined lambda inside a class template function? For example

```
template <typename T> 
class X{
public:
        X();
        //rest of declaration
private:
        //rest of declaration
};

template<typename T> X<T>::X(){

     function<void()>someLambda = [] (){
        //recursive definition
        };

     //rest of definition
}
```

I tried using `__func__` but that prints the function name as `operator()`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compiler there may be other symbols available, gcc has **PRETTY_FUNCTION** and msvc has __FUNCDNAME_ (as well as a couple others)